# What does cudaSetDevice() do to a CUDA device's context stack?

Tags: cuda, cuda-context, cuda-driver

Suppose I have an active CUDA context associated with device `i`, and I now call `cudaSetDevice(i)`. What happens? :

1. Nothing?
2. Primary context replaces the top of the stack?
3. Primary context is pushed onto the stack?

It actually seems to be inconsistent. I've written this program, running on a machine with a single device:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        CUcontext ctx1, primary;
        cuInit(0);
        auto status = cuCtxCreate(&ctx1, 0, 0);
        assert (status == (CUresult) cudaSuccess);
        cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx1);
        status = cudaSetDevice(0);
        assert (status == cudaSuccess);
        void* ptr1;
        void* ptr2;
        cudaMalloc(&ptr1, 1024);
        assert (status == cudaSuccess);
        cuCtxGetCurrent(&primary);
        assert (status == (CUresult) cudaSuccess);
        assert(primary != ctx1);
        status = cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx1);
        assert (status == (CUresult) cudaSuccess);
        cudaMalloc(&ptr2, 1024);
        assert (status == (CUresult) cudaSuccess);
        cudaSetDevice(0);
        assert (status == (CUresult) cudaSuccess);
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
                status = cuCtxPopCurrent(&primary);
                if (status != (CUresult) cudaSuccess) { break; }
                std::cout << "Next context on stack (" << i++ << ") is " << (void*) primary << '\n';
        }
}
```

and I get the following output:

```
context ctx1 is 0x563ec6225e30
primary context is 0x563ec61f5490
Next context on stack (0) is 0x563ec61f5490
Next context on stack (1) is 0x563ec61f5490
Next context on stack(2) is 0x563ec6225e3
```

This seems like the behavior is *sometimes* a replacement, and *sometimes* a push.

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR:  Based on the code you have provided, in both instances of your particular usage, it seems that `cudaSetDevice()` is replacing the context at the top of the stack.

Let's modify your code a bit, and then see what we can infer about the effect of each API call in your code on the context stack:

```
$ cat t1759.cu
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
void check(int j, CUcontext ctx1, CUcontext ctx2){
  CUcontext ctx0;
  int i = 0;
  while (true) {
                auto status = cuCtxPopCurrent(&ctx0);
                if (status != CUDA_SUCCESS) { break; }
                if (ctx0 == ctx1) std::cout << j << ":Next context on stack (" << i++ << ") is ctx1:" << (void*) ctx0 << '\n';
                else if (ctx0 == ctx2) std::cout << j << ":Next context on stack (" << i++ << ") is ctx2:" << (void*) ctx0 << '\n';
                else std::cout << j << ":Next context on stack (" << i++ << ") is unknown:" << (void*) ctx0 << '\n';
  }
}
void runtest(int i)
{
        CUcontext ctx1, primary = NULL;
        cuInit(0);
        auto dstatus = cuCtxCreate(&ctx1, 0, 0);    // checkpoint 1
        assert (dstatus == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        if (i == 1) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 1
        dstatus = cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx1);           // checkpoint 2
        assert (dstatus == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        if (i == 2) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 2
        auto rstatus = cudaSetDevice(0);            // checkpoint 3
        assert (rstatus == cudaSuccess);
        if (i == 3) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 3
        void* ptr1;
        void* ptr2;
        rstatus = cudaMalloc(&ptr1, 1024);          // checkpoint 4
        assert (rstatus == cudaSuccess);
        if (i == 4) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 4
        dstatus = cuCtxGetCurrent(&primary);        // checkpoint 5
        assert (dstatus == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        assert(primary != ctx1);
        if (i == 5) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 5
        dstatus = cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx1);           // checkpoint 6
        assert (dstatus == CUDA_SUCCESS);
        if (i == 6) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 6
        rstatus = cudaMalloc(&ptr2, 1024);          // checkpoint 7
        assert (rstatus == cudaSuccess);
        if (i == 7) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 7
        rstatus = cudaSetDevice(0);                 // checkpoint 8
        assert (rstatus == cudaSuccess);
        if (i == 8) {check(i,ctx1,primary); return;}// checkpoint 8
        return;
}

int main(){
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
          cudaDeviceReset();
          runtest(i);}
}
$ nvcc -o t1759 t1759.cu -lcuda -std=c++11
$ ./t1759
1:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x11087e0
2:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x1741160
2:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x1741160
3:Next context on stack (0) is unknown:0x10dc520
3:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x1c5aa70
4:Next context on stack (0) is unknown:0x10dc520
4:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x23eaa00
5:Next context on stack (0) is ctx2:0x10dc520
5:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x32caf30
6:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x3a44ed0
6:Next context on stack (1) is ctx2:0x10dc520
6:Next context on stack (2) is ctx1:0x3a44ed0
7:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x41cfd90
7:Next context on stack (1) is ctx2:0x10dc520
7:Next context on stack (2) is ctx1:0x41cfd90
8:Next context on stack (0) is ctx2:0x10dc520
8:Next context on stack (1) is ctx2:0x10dc520
8:Next context on stack (2) is ctx1:0x4959c70
$
```

Based on the above, as we proceed through each API call in your code:

1.

```
        auto dstatus = cuCtxCreate(&ctx1, 0, 0);    // checkpoint 1
1:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x11087e0
```

The context creation also pushes the newly created context on the stack, as mentioned [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX.html#group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX_1g9051f2d5c31501997a6cb0530290a300).

2.

```
        dstatus = cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx1);           // checkpoint 2
2:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x1741160
2:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x1741160
```

No surprise, pushing the same context on the stack creates another stack entry for it.

3.

```
        auto rstatus = cudaSetDevice(0);            // checkpoint 3
3:Next context on stack (0) is unknown:0x10dc520
3:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x1c5aa70
```

The `cudaSetDevice()` call has *replaced* the top of the stack with an "unknown" context. (Only unknown at this point because we have not retrieved the handle value of the "other" context).

4.

```
        rstatus = cudaMalloc(&ptr1, 1024);          // checkpoint 4
4:Next context on stack (0) is unknown:0x10dc520
4:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x23eaa00
```

No difference in stack configuration due to this call.

5.

```
        dstatus = cuCtxGetCurrent(&primary);        // checkpoint 5
5:Next context on stack (0) is ctx2:0x10dc520
5:Next context on stack (1) is ctx1:0x32caf30
```

No difference in stack configuration due to this call, but we now know that the top of stack context is the current context (and we can surmise it is the primary context).

6.

```
        dstatus = cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx1);           // checkpoint 6
6:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x3a44ed0
6:Next context on stack (1) is ctx2:0x10dc520
6:Next context on stack (2) is ctx1:0x3a44ed0
```

No real surprise here.  We are pushing `ctx1` on the stack, and so the stack has 3 entries, the first one being the driver API created context, and the next two entries being the same as the stack configuration from step 5, just moved down one stack location.

7.

```
        rstatus = cudaMalloc(&ptr2, 1024);          // checkpoint 7
7:Next context on stack (0) is ctx1:0x41cfd90
7:Next context on stack (1) is ctx2:0x10dc520
7:Next context on stack (2) is ctx1:0x41cfd90
```

Again, this call has no effect on stack configuration.

8.

```
        rstatus = cudaSetDevice(0);                 // checkpoint 8
8:Next context on stack (0) is ctx2:0x10dc520
8:Next context on stack (1) is ctx2:0x10dc520
8:Next context on stack (2) is ctx1:0x4959c70
```

Once again, we see that the behavior here is that the `cudaSetDevice()` call has *replaced* the top of stack context with the primary context.

The conclusion I have from your test code is that I see *no* inconsistency of behavior of the `cudaSetDevice()` call when intermixed with various runtime and driver API calls as you have in your code.

From my perspective, this sort of programming paradigm is insanity.  I can't imagine why you would want to intermix driver API and runtime API code this way.

Comment: Oh, no, I don't want to do that, it was an artificial example I just wanted to understand the behavior, so that when I extend my API wrappers to the driver API, I won't mess things up with false assumptions.

Comment: Right now, I have code which "pushes" and "pops" the current device - assuming only the runtime API is used. Now that you've clarified how `cudaSetDevice()` behaves, I can change that code to do: 1. Peek at the current context. 2. Save it on the side. 3. `cudaSetDevice()` to the device I want to work with using the Runtime API 4. Do my work. 5. `cuCtxSetCurrent()` to the context I saved.

Comment: With your edit of my answer you've made a declaration I'm not comfortable with, and effectively attributed that declaration to me.  It's probably better if you don't edit my answers (unless I mark them as community wiki).  I'm not comfortable with that and I'd advise against taking such liberties with my answers in the future.  I'm comfortable making statements about what I observe.  Let's leave it at that.  If you desire something further, my suggestion is to make such requests via the bug filing portal at developer.nvidia.com.  If you desire clarification, please use the comments.

Comment: Additionally, I make no statements about your 5 steps that you have now laid out in the comments.

Comment: I'll respect your suggests and requests.

Comment: I've used this insight in the implementation of my [combined Runtime + Driver API wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/tree/driver-wrappers) in Modern C++. Thanks (and if you happen to have feedback on that, it would be most welcome).